# For loop what does this mean?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

i'm learning Java at the moment and am learning how to parse HTML.

i understand how for loops work

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
}
```

means that i is 0, if i is less than 20 then increase by 1.

But what does this mean????

```
for(Element newsHeadline: newsHeadlines){
                    System.out.println(newsHeadline.attr("href"));
                }
```

i have tried googleing this but can't find answer

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Java for each loop work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Comment: ^^ Checkout aliteralmind's answer in that thread as it goes into detail about syntax and how to use.

Answer (score 2):

This is a `foreach` loop.

`newsHeadlines` is an array of objects of type `Element`.

```
for(Element newsHeadline: newsHeadlines)
```

Should be read as

`For each newsHeadline in newsHeadlines do`

It will end after it reaches the last object of `newsHeadlines` and finishes the code in the block.

Hopefully now that you know it is a foreach loop, it will help you refine your Google search.

Answer (score 1):

It's a for-each loop. It uses iterator to iterate over collection

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 1):

For loop is a short form of original for loop, but without index of given element.

As an example:

```
for(Element newsHeadline: newsHeadlines){
   System.out.println(newsHeadline.attr("href"));
}
```

is same as:

```
Iterator<Element> it  = newsHeadlines.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
   Element newsHeadline = it.next();
   System.out.println(newsHeadline.attr("href"));
}
```

As you can see it is shorter and more readable. In short it means: for every element in collection do something. You can iterate over any iterable collection or array.

Answer (score 1):

It is `for-each` loop. It is shorthand for writing for loop eliminating the use of index.

```
String[] names = {"Alex", "Adam"};

for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i ++) {
    System.out.println(names[i]);
}

for(String name: names) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an iterating loop: each iteration puts the next element of the collection `newsHeadlines` inside `newsHeadline`.
Checkout this thread:
[How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you.

Example:

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]){
      int [] numbers = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

      for(int x : numbers ){
         System.out.print( x );
         System.out.print(",");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
      String [] names ={"James", "Larry", "Tom", "Lacy"};
      for( String name : names ) {
         System.out.print( name );
         System.out.print(",");
      }
   }
}
This would produce the following result:

10,20,30,40,50,
James,Larry,Tom,Lacy,
```